# TypeScript type declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Can someone explain to me what exactly this declaration means in TypeScript? I know that with **type** and **interface** I can create new data types. But  I really can not understand this statement.

```
 type ParameterizedContext<StateT = DefaultState, CustomT = DefaultContext> = ExtendableContext & {
        state: StateT;
    } & CustomT;
```

I found this at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/koa/index.d.ts

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParameterizedContext<StateT = DefaultState, CustomT = DefaultContext>
```

This is the start of defining a generic type. `StateT` and `CustomT` are placeholders which you can fill in with any type you like, though if you don't fill them in it will use `DefaultState` and `DefaultContext`.

For example, if you create a `ParameterizedContext<{ foo: string }, { bar: number }>`, then `StateT` is becomes `{ foo: string }` everywhere in the type and `CustomT` becomes `{ bar: number }`

```
ExtendableContext & {
  state: StateT;
} & CustomT;
```

This means that it has all of the properties of ExtendableContext, plus a state property who's type is `StateT`, plus all of the properties of `CustomT`.

So continuing the example from above, if `StateT` is `{ foo: string }` and `CustomT` is `{ bar: number }`, then this type is the following

```
{
  // ... imagine all the properties of ExtendableContext being here (i don't know what they are)
  state: { foo: string },
  bar: number,
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation Mr. Nicholas thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator allow to create [intersection-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types). `A & B` is a type which is A and B, has all the properties of A and all the properties of B.

In your type, `ParameterizedContext` is an `ExtendableContext` plus a property called `state` of type `StateT` plus all the properties of `CustomT`

`StateT` and `CustomT` are [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). generics allow to reuse type definition by adding parameters.

`StateT` by default is an `DefaultState` which is defined as `any`. `CustomT`  by default is a `DefaultContext` which is defined by a `Record<string, any>`.